# Error in Compiling Code not showing any specific error in nodejs with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am developing a program to perform CRUD programs and i am getting a unknown error -

```
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\practiceofmongonode.js:13:9)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

here is the code of nodejs file
In which i defined the routes

```
var express               =    require("express"),
    app                   =    express(),
    bodyParser            =    require("body-parser"),
    mongoose              =    require("mongoose");

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/practiceofmn");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

    var books = new mongoose.Schema({
        title:String,
        author:String
    });
    app.use("view engine","ejs");
    app.get("/",function(req,res){
        res.render("book");
    });

    app.post("/addbook",function(req,res){
var book = mongoose.model("book",books);
var title2 = req.body.title1;
var author2 = req.body.author1;

book.create({title:title2,author:author2},function(err,book){

                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                            }
                        else{
                            res.send(book);
                        }
});
    });

    app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("i am serving you");
        });
```

here is the code of book.ejs 
In this file i am getting input from user

```
<h1>hello here you can create new post</h1>
<form action="/addbook" method="POST">
<input type="text" name = "title1" placeholder="title here" > 

<input type="text" name = "author1" placeholder="author name here" >

<input type = "submit">
</form>
```

Comment: show use the first lines of the error

Comment: Error occur during startup or during making request?

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak during startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `app.set` for setup view engine not `app.use`.

http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html#developing-template-engines-for-express

The response was in error. `Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))`